# Makefile: Compiling without Linking Issue

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

Currently I'm trying to compile .c-files in subfolder(s) without linking and created a simple draft in Makefile. What I want to do is take .o files into bin/ directory without linking as I described before. However couldn't reach any output successfully.

There is sample Makefile:

```
IDIR = test/inc
ODIR = test/src
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -I$(IDIR)

OBJDIR    =   bin

.PHONY: clean

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir   $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o:  $(ODIR)/*.c
    $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   -c  $<  -o  $@

clean:
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
```

It would be great if you define what did I missed.

Comment: How do you run the make, what is the expected vs actual output ?

Comment: @dash-o I didn't define any specific target to make linking. Instead, just expected the create .o files into bin/ directory and the result is that just creates bin/ directory without any .o files when I run make command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the make file needs to actually ask for all the object files to be created.  Suggest:

```
IDIR := test/inc
SDIR := test/src/

CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c99 -I$(IDIR)

OBJDIR    :=   bin/

SRCS := (wildcard:$(SDIR)*.c)
OBJS := ($(SRCS):.c=.o)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJDIR)  $(OBJS)


$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir   $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)%.o:  %.c
    $(CC)   $(CFLAGS)   -c  $<  -o  $@

clean:
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
```

run the above makefile using:

```
make -f (your make file name) all
```